# Pagination and limit data in Magento2

Tags: magento2

I am new in magento2. I am trying to set pagination and limit it accordingly in my custom FAQ module.

I am trying to use default pagination of magento2. I am getting the pagination in frontend but there is no limit to the data.

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    $collection1 = $this->_modelFactory->getCollection();

    parent::_prepareLayout();
    if ($collection1) {
        $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager','my.custom.pager');
        $pager->setLimit(1)->setCollection($collection1);
        $pager->setAvailableLimit([1=>1,2=>2,50=>50,100=>100]);
        $this->setChild('pager', $pager);// set pager block in layout

    }
    return $this;
}

public function getPagerHtml()
{
    return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
}
```

[image]

It should show me only 1 FAQ but it shows 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rearange this code:

```
$pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager','my.custom.pager');
$pager->setLimit(1)->setCollection($collection1);
$pager->setAvailableLimit([1=>1,2=>2,50=>50,100=>100]);
$this->setChild('pager', $pager);
```

to look like this:

```
$pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager','my.custom.pager');
$pager->setAvailableLimit([1=>1,2=>2,50=>50,100=>100]);
$pager->setCollection($collection1);
$this->setChild('pager', $pager);
```

You need to set the available limits before passing the collection object to the pager, because when you add the collection to the pager, [the limits are already applied to the collection](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Theme/Block/Html/Pager.php#L170).
Any modifications you add to the limits after setting the collection are ignored.

Comment: in this example, 'my.custom.pager'  is phtml file name ? I just want to know, your help would be really appreciated my friend

Comment: No. It is just the block alias